# getElementsByClassName - Template inserted direct child can not be found under specific conditions

Tags: javascript

**TLDR** - See example HTML. First `console.log` call shows an empty `resultset`. I know how the fix this, but why does this happen? Chrome (101.0.4951.54) / Edge (101.0.1210.32)

I ran into the following issue: calling `getElementsByClassName` with a case sensitive name (`inputStartState`) on a container which has a direct child with said class name, the result is empty.

However: this only occurs when the element has been added using a template element AND an event listener has been attached to said element BEFORE inserting the template into the DOM.

This happens in Chrome (101.0.4951.54) and Edge (101.0.1210.32), but FireFox (100.0) is not affected.

Example:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="tester"></div>
  <template id="testTemplate">
    <div class="test"><input class="inputStartState"></div>
  </template>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var container = document.getElementById("tester");
      container.innerHTML = "";
      var template = document.getElementById("testTemplate");
      var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
      var root = clone.firstElementChild;
// remove the line below line and it will work just fine - WHY?
      root.getElementsByClassName("inputStartState")[0].onblur = function() {   
        console.log("Blurrrrr");
      }
      container.append(clone);

      var el = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];
      console.log("Direct parent, with case: ",  el.getElementsByClassName("inputStartState"));
      console.log("Direct parent, lower case: ",el.getElementsByClassName("inputstartstate"));
        
      el = document.getElementById("tester");
      console.log("Parent's parent, with case: ",el.getElementsByClassName("inputStartState"));
      console.log("Parent's parent, lower case: ", el.getElementsByClassName("inputstartstate"));
})();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Running this piece of script yields the following output to the console

> Chrome (101.0.4951.54) / Edge (101.0.1210.32)
> Direct parent, with case:  HTMLCollection []
> Direct parent, lower case:  HTMLCollection [input.inputstartstate]
> Parent's parent, with case:  HTMLCollection [input.inputstartstate]
> Parent's parent, lower case:  HTMLCollection [input.inputstartstate]

The easy fix is to attach the event after inserting the template into the DOM.
I'm more curious as to WHY doing it this way causes this weird, and very specific bug.

Answer (score 0):

var testContainer = document.querySelector('#test');
var childNodeByClass = testContainer.querySelector('.my-class');

Comment: As mentioned, I know how to fix this. My question is, why does this specific set of instructions yield this bug?

Comment: I want to get only direct child elements with getElementsByClassName. Now I have e.g. this HTML

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).